# taskwarrior "task del" without confirmation dialog

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, confirmation, taskwarrior

In taskwarrior there are some commands which need confirmirmation, like deleting more than 2 tasks or modify recurring tasks. I don't want to confirm every time and I have already set "confirmation off" in file .taskrc .

I'm using the subprocess module in python to invoke taskwarrior commands. I'm calling for example `task del 1,2,3` and the shell waits now for a manual confirmation of the deletion request.

How can I avoid the manual confirmation?

Comment: Made it more readable...

Answer (score 3):

You should add `confirmation=no` to `~/.taskrc`.

Here's a one-liner to do that:

```
echo confirmation=no >> ~/.taskrc
```

Answer (score 1):

already added `confirmation=no` to `~/.taskrc`

a possible answer to the question could be

`echo 'all' | task del 1,2,3`

but there could be a better one

Comment: What version of `task` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

To disable confirmations entirely, I have the following in my `taskrc`:

```
# no confirmation on bulk actions
confirmation=off
bulk=0
```

This command will remove tasks `1`, `2` and `3` without asking for confirmation:

```bash
$ task rc.bulk=0 rc.confirmation=off 1-3 delete
```